# Unable to instantiate Google API Service: Permission Denied

Tags: python, google-api, google-custom-search, api-key, google-api-python-client

I made a project in my Google account. Then authorized and access to Google Custom Search with an API Key and an ID to a Custom Search Engine.
I tried to perform a search using the Python interface, by modifying the sample code.
Every time I run the code after this line I get this error:

```
service = build("customsearch", "v1",
        developerKey="AIxx")
```

> IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

I tried to create a request myself to check if the problem is with Google or me. Here is my request:

> https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=olive+garden&cx=00026xx&key=AIxx

And it worked! So, now I'm completely confused, and cannot figure out what the problem is.

It's even more strange because when I try to perform the same search using Google APIs explorer, it returns: Daily Limit Exceeded

Comment: Run it with super user, maybe this help you.

Comment: @HasanRamezani you mean to run python using sudo?

Comment: run your script by super user. something like this: `sudo python test.py`

Comment: @HasanRamezani It worked. Do you have any idea how I can fix it to work with out a need for sudo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem is because httplib2 installer don't set read permission for others on cacerts.txt
you must add read permission to others too :D

```
sudo chmod o+r /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/httplib2-0.9.2-py2.7.egg/httplib2/cacerts.txt
```

actually httplib2 must read this from system wide certificates and i don't know why they don't. is there anybody that know why? there is patches for this specific problem like this patch for example https://bugs.mageia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=6568

Comment: Fixed. Doesn't it have any side-effects? Is it safe by any means?

Comment: yes it's safe this file is root certificates for certificate authorities see this (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_certificate)

Comment: see https://github.com/jcgregorio/httplib2/issues/252 for complete information about this issue

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because Google API want to access the location that not permission to it.

Run your script by super user. something like this:

```
sudo python test.py
```

If you know the location that Google API want to access, change the permission of location by `chmod` command.